# How do I make a Java project use a custom library while retaining access to source without manually buidling the library JAR?

Tags: java, gradle, lib

I have several Java gradle projects that all need to interpret the same data, so I'd like to make a library to share across the projects.

Normally (in C++), I would create a new project for the library, and then include it in each of the other projects as a git submodule, then include instructions to build the library and depend on it. I like this a lot because I can see the source of the library in each of the projects and debug into them, which is helpful since the library and the other projects are being developed together. I may find a bug in the library, or maybe I just want to change something, and it's very easy to do.

To be clear, what I would like to do is include my Java library as a submodule and edit my `build.gradle` file so that when I build my project, it will build and "link" the library, but I want to keep the ability to access and modify the source of the library. I *don't* want to have to open a different project, compile a JAR, and copy it to a dependencies directory each time I make a library change. I also want to "statically" link the library so I can deploy just one JAR.

In Java, this doesn't seem to work well. I tried to just include the source, but I run into problems with package name. If I have my library as `com.acme.lib`, I can't include that include that in `com.acme.proj1` since the directories already exist.

For more detail, my library is laid out like so

```
src
└── main
    └── java
        └── com
            └── acme
                └── Library.java
```

and my projects are laid out like so

```
src
└── main
    └── java
        └── com
            └── acme
                └── Project1.java
```

Given that most of the package structure is the same, I can't build both, I get package name errors from one or the other.

I haven't found any other way to do this in my research. Is this possible? Or should I be going about this completely differently and using a Java convention that I'm unaware of?

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA if it matters.

Comment: _"I get package name errors"_ - without a lot more detail we really can't help.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm basically just saying that you can't have two `src` directories. From the research I've done, I don't think Java is supposed to operate this way, so I didn't put a lot of time into it. Am I wrong?

Comment: So you only want to share some source files at compile time but at runtime there should be no trace of your “library” anymore, right? And the library will never need to produce its own JAR file? That should be possible with Java and Git submodules (even though it’d be rather uncommon). I wonder how exactly you’ve set this up and what exact errors you’re facing; can you maybe provide a [mcve]?